# Can't bind to 'matTooltipPosition' since it isn't a known property of 'button'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

i'm trying to integrate a new Angular theme, so after finishing the install of dependencies

- i got this problem

> ERROR in src/app/dashboard/dashboard.component.html:171:110 - error
> NG8002: Can't bind to 'matTooltipPosition' since it isn't a known
> property of 'button'. 171
> <button mat-raised-button type="button" matTooltip="Edit Task"
> [matTooltipPosition]="'above'" class="btn btn-primary btn-link btn-sm
> btn-just-icon">

```
                                     <td class="td-actions text-right">
                                          <button mat-raised-button type="button" matTooltip="Edit Task" [matTooltipPosition]="'above'" class="btn btn-primary btn-link btn-sm btn-just-icon">
                                              <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                                          </button>
                                          <button mat-raised-button type="button" matTooltip="Remove" [matTooltipPosition]="'above'" class="btn btn-danger btn-link btn-sm btn-just-icon">
                                              <i class="material-icons">close</i>
                                          </button>
                                      </td>
```

you can find the deps in this [link](https://ghostbin.co/paste/8ew9x)

Comment: Did you import the MatTooltipModule in your NgModule imports?

Edit: Afaik you do need to install @angular/material to use the button & tooltip components. I did not spot them in your deps.

Comment: yes, i've already  install it from : https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular2-material/tooltip and still get the error

Comment: He ment importing a module, not npm package. [That one](https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/api) to be precise. There's tons of similar topics on SO though. And [here's](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1#the-missing-formsmodule) the description of that in official tutorial for Angular.

Comment: i try it the issue

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are using the angular material components in your code afaik.

So you first need to install the @angular/material libary:

```
   npm i @angular/material
```

After installing you just import the needed component modules in your ngModule:

```
    import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material/tooltip';
    
   @ngModule({
        imports: [..., MatTooltipModule]
     })
```

To get started with angular/material:

https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

Answer (score 4):

The above answer is perfectly alright but to add some more information,

If you are using modular approach then you might need to import it into your current module too.

[image]

As in my case from the above image. I need to import it into my "setting-manager.module.ts"

```
import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material/tooltip';
@ngModule({
    imports: [MatTooltipModule]
})
```